# Autobiographer badge when linking account on multiple stack exchange websites

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, hyperlinks

I have noticed that when you link your account on multiple stack exchange websites the "autobiographer" badge does not automatically get awarded even though all the profile fields are populated.

Is this by design or an oversight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a website listed on your meta profile, or any of the accounts linked from it, therefore you are not eligible for the Autobiographer badge on those sites...

Comment: the autobiographer rule must have changed recently. I don't have it on stack overflow account but I have the autobiographer badge.

Comment: you are correct. The rules must have changed. Filling that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Most badges take a while to be awarded. Some are nearly instant, others take minutes or longer. It depends on the badge and the work involved to determine who is eligible. Give it a while.

Comment: By awhile do you mean 6+ months?

Comment: @CoolBeans in my case, I get the badge on the same day, for what it's worth.

Comment: In the time it took me to find this post, enough time had passed that I'd gotten the badge ;)  +1!

Answer (score 1):

There's a job that runs periodically to award badges.  Your badge will get awarded at the next job run.

Comment: Does the job run very infrequently? I am talking 6 months or more.

Comment: @CoolBeans Oh no, that's an issue.  I get Autobiographers typically in a matter of minutes when linking accounts.